# Error while connecting to SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

> An error occured while establishing a connection to the
>   server. When connecting to the SQL
>   server 2005, the failure may be caused
>   by the fact that under the default
>   settings SQL server does not allow
>   remote connections. (provider: Named
>   pipes provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL server)

I am using .NET framework provider for SQL Server and Visual Studio 2008.

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know external references are bad, but it really does not get better than this:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

as they say

```
 Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Comment: Great site, I use them often.

Answer (score 1):

AttachDbFilename should be the path to the database filed (generally a .mdf) that you will be using.

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\some.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

Answer (score 1):

> An error occured while establishing a
>   connection to the server. When
>   connecting to the SQL server 2005, the
>   failure may be caused by the fact that
>   under the default settings SQL server
>   does not allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named pipes provider,
>   error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL server)

By default SQL Server Express disables remote connections via TCP/IP and Named Pipes, so you will need to enable these protocols in the SQL Server Configuration Manager (Start --> Programs --> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 --> Configuration Tools).

[image]

I also agree with Hogan about ConnectionStrings.com great site!